# Reading from a file and storing the first Integer as a String and the rest as Integers

Tags: java

I am trying to read a file and store the individual integers, but make the first integer in the file into a String. I have been able to read the file but I am struggling to store the integers respectively. I want to use them within the program.

The file has three integers per line separated by a whitespace.

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class arrayListStuffs2 {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Please enter the file name: e.g \'test.txt\'");
    String fileName = sc.nextLine();
    try {
       sc = new Scanner(new File(fileName));
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    List<String> listS = new ArrayList<>();
    List<Integer> listI = new ArrayList<>();

    while (sc.hasNextLine()) {
        listI.add(sc.nextInt());
    }
    System.out.println(listI);
 }
}
```

Comment: Well you never store anything in your `listS`, if you wonder why it's empty.

Comment: Can you share the data which your file contains?

Comment: Can you provide an example for what you are trying to achieve?

Comment: The file just has numbers in it e.g 1 3 4 and the next line 5 7 8. So I want to make the first number to be stored as a String. That would be 1 and 5 in this case. and the rest would be stored as integers, so that I can call them as variables within a different class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the following approach. Iterate lines, split it, take first as string and other two as integer (assuming that you have data as

```
1 2 3
4 5 6
7 8 9
```

):

```
List<String> listS = new ArrayList();
List<Integer> listI = new ArrayList();
// try with resource automatically close resources
try (BufferedReader reader = Files.newBufferedReader(Paths.get("res.txt"))) 
{
    reader.lines().forEach(line -> {
        String[] ints = line.split(" ");
        listS.add(String.valueOf(ints[0]));
        listI.add(Integer.parseInt(ints[1]));
        listI.add(Integer.parseInt(ints[2]));
    });

} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Output is :

[image]

Comment: I think you forgot to close your stream.

Comment: Thanks, worked great, I added a third list and was able to iterate through all of them using list.get().